# Loop two data frames to make meta analysis

Tags: r, analysis, meta

I have `DF1` and `DF2` with equal dimension, for example,

```
DF1
hr  se         m
1   0.5   1.5  a 
2   1.5   2.5  b
3   2.5   3.5  c
4   3.5   4.5  d

DF2
hr  se         m
5   4.5   5.5  a
6   5.5   6.5  b
7   6.5   7.5  c
8   7.5   8.5  d
```

I need to make meta analysis.
I know that for all rows of one `DF`, i can make it as

```
library(rmeta)
d <- meta.summaries(DF1$hr, DF1$se, names = DF1$m, method = c("fixed"))
```

But what i want is to make meta analysis for every row of these two data frames. For example, `row 1` of `DF1` is meta analysed with `row 1` of `DF2`. 
I might suppose that i need loop or `lapply` function.
Thank you for any tips or suggestions.

Comment: unclear to me, could you provide an example of the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to just use `rbind` and then `split` by `m` to get a list:

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
split(df3, df3$m)

$a
  hr  se   x m
1  1 0.5 1.5 a
5  5 4.5 5.5 a

$b
  hr  se   x m
2  2 1.5 2.5 b
6  6 5.5 6.5 b

$c
  hr  se   x m
3  3 2.5 3.5 c
7  7 6.5 7.5 c

$d
  hr  se   x m
4  4 3.5 4.5 d
8  8 7.5 8.5 d
```

You can then use a `for` loop or `lapply` to get the results. For that, just Google for `for loop R` or `apply family R`.

Comment: Can you please help me more..I tried `for loop` . I tried `for(i in 1:length(A)){
  out<-meta.summaries(A$hr, A$se, names = A$metabolite, method = c("fixed"))}`, where `A` is split `df`

Comment: Close :) I think that it should be `A[[i]]` within the `meta.summaries` function, since `A` is a list. With `A[[i]]` you extract the ith data frame, on which you can then do `$hr` and such.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing :) but if i do like this `for (i in 1:length(A))
{out<-meta.summaries(A[[i]]$hr, A[[i]]$se,
                     names = A[[i]]$metabolite, method = c("fixed"))}` it returns me `arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 0`. Should it be something `for (i,j)`?

Comment: Ah, yes, you wrote `A[[i]]$metabolite`. If you are using the example data, then this won't work, as the column `metabolite` doesn't exist. Try `A[[i]]$m`. If you are not using the example data, then I can't immediately think of a reason.

Comment: Yep. im not using example data, `m` and `metabolite` are actually same. Just for simplicity i made it to be `m`. Anyway thanks a lot! It was great tip!